# Roboguice: using manual injections causes ConfigurationException (no implementation was bound)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice, roboblender

I've found an issue with Roboguice when using manual instance resolution. It works once I turn off the Annotation Database. Otherwise I get the exception:

```
No implementation for com.kmsoftware.roboguicetest.SomeInterface was bound.
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a Robolectric/Roboblender bug?

The code looks like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends RoboActionBarActivity {

//    static {
//        RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(false);
//    }

    @Inject
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activityMainLabel);

        SomeInterface instance = RoboGuice.getInjector(this).getInstance(SomeInterface.class);

        tv.setText(String.valueOf(instance.getValue()));
    }

    ...
}
```

**RoboModule.java**

```
public class RoboModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        bind(SomeInterface.class).to(ConcreteClass.class);
    }
}
```

**SomeInterface.java**

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    int getValue();
}
```

**ConcreteClass.java**

```
public class ConcreteClass implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a bug in Roboguice/Roboblender. There is a fix, it hasn't been committed yet, and I haven't managed to make it work. I am not using the annotation database at the moment.

Comment: With Roboguice 4.0, the roboblender works out of the box.